# Flat File Destination has multiple Inputs from custom data flow task

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSIS Package setup with the following Data Flow Tasks in order:

1. Flat File Source
2. Derived Column
3. Custom Task
4. Flat File Destination

---

- The Flat File source contains fixed-width rows of data (282 characters per row).
- The Derived Column splits each row into columns using the `SUBSTRING()` method.
- The Custom Task performs some Regular Expression validation and creates two new output columns: `RowIsValid` (a `DT_BOOL`) and `InvalidReason` (a `DT_WSTR` of 200).  There is no Custom UI for this Task.
- The Flat File Destination is the validated data in delimited column format.  Eventually, this would be a
  database destination.

---

I know that this can be done using a `Script Task`.  In fact, I am currently doing so in my solution.  However, what I am trying to accomplish is building a Custom Task so that code changes are done in a single-spot instead of having to change multiple `Script Tasks`.

I have a couple of issues I'm trying to overcome and am hoping for some help/guidance:

1. (*Major*) Currently, when I review the mappings of the Flat File Destination, the Available Input columns are coming from the Flat File Source, the Derived Column Task, and the Custom Task.  Only one column is coming from the Flat File Source (because there is only one column), while the Derived Column and Custom Task each have all of the columns created in the Derived Column.

   My expectation is that the Available Input Columns would/should only display the `Custom Validator.[column name]` columns (with only the column name) from the Custom Validator.  Debugging, I don't see where I can manipulate and suppress the `Derived Column.[column name]` columns.
2. (*Minor*) Getting the input columns from the Derived Column Task to automatically be selected or used when the Input is attached.

   Currently, after hooking up the input and output of the Custom Validator, I have to go to the Inputs tab on the Advanced Edit and select the columns I want.  I'm selecting all, because I want all columns to go through the task, even though only some will be validated by the task.

Comment: Problem #1 --> Have two new outputs from script task that only contain the columns you want to see and remove the original output.

Comment: Also, you can't have 2 inputs into a destination. You will have to union all before that. If you are not doing anything with the split rows, I am not sure why you would split it

Comment: Did you try suppressing columns in the Advanced Editor of the Derived Column component?

Comment: @KeithL I think you misunderstood what I was trying to illustrate.  I have added a bit more information which I hope helps.  Each step of the task only has a single input/output.  I am splitting a single fixed-width row into multiple columns using the `Derived Column`.  Additionally, I am creating two new output columns within the code of the Custom Task.  Values for these columns are set based on the calculations being performed within the Custom Task.

Comment: @TabAlleman I don't see that option in the Advanced Editor of the Derived Column component.  Wouldn't that prevent the data from going through the Derived Column and into the Custom Task?